# Angular factory returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, factory

I can't seem to pass an object from a Factory to a Controller. I know this should be very simple, but I'm stumped.

```
app.factory('test', [function(){
    var fac = {};
    fac.users = ['john', 'james', 'jake'];
    return fac;
}]);

app.controller('dashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'test',
    function($scope, test){
        $scope.testFunction = function(){
            console.log(test.users);
        }
     }
]);
```

Firing $scope.testFunction results in "undefined" logged in the console.

Comment: When and where are you firing `$scope.testFunction`?  It seems to work fine on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tgohyp3/2/)

Comment: @PenVirus make a jsfiddle and show us. This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a working code sample. Make sure the latest version of your Angular factory/controller files are being referenced in the DOM, and try again.